# Visvaksena : a jivaatma or a Visnu tattva?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, avatars

There's a nityasuri of Lord Visnu called Visvaksena who is described as being the Commander-in-Chief of Lord Visnu's army. There's also an incarnation by the same name. Are these two the same Person? Is Visvaksena a jivaatma or a Visnu tattva? Please provide scriptural references if possible.